# How to implement a string array in a query?

Tags: android, sql, android-room

I want to get data from my room db with the following query:

```
  @Query("SELECT address.address_id, first_name, last_name, street, postal_code, city," +
"(SELECT employee.employee_id FROM employee WHERE employee.address_id = address.address_id) AS employee_id, " +
"(SELECT project.project_id FROM project WHERE project.address_id = address.address_id) AS project_id " +
"FROM address WHERE last_name IN (:pattern) OR first_name IN (:pattern) ORDER BY last_name ASC, first_name ASC") 
LiveData<List<AddressBookAddress>> loadAddressBookWithFilter(String... pattern);
```

As you can see my parameter accepts an array with one or more search strings.

Let's take for example "max" and "muster"

Now I want to get all records which contain the first names "max" or "muster" or the last names "max" or "muster". But currently, I'm not receiving any data at all.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The docs show it as quite straightforward thing. Look at [Room Query docs](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/arch/persistence/room/Query). There you can see this example:

> As an extension over SQLite bind arguments, Room supports binding a list of parameters to the query. At runtime, Room will build the correct query to have matching number of bind arguments depending on the number of items in the method parameter.
>
> ```
> @Query("SELECT * FROM user WHERE uid IN(:userIds)")
> public abstract List findByIds(int[] userIds);
> ```
>
> For the example above, if the userIds is an array of 3 elements, Room will run the query as: SELECT * FROM user WHERE uid IN(?, ?, ?) and bind each item in the userIds array into the statement.

So, change signature from "String..." to "String[]" to clearly state an array presence.

Answer (score 0):

There is no document for kotlin on [this page](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/arch/persistence/room/Query.html) but you can use this code for the same.

```
 @Query("SELECT * FROM employee WHERE id IN(:idList)")
 fun getAllSelectedEmployee(idList:Array<String?>): List<Model>
```